# URL rewriting in PHP using htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My URL is

`localhost/Interview/php/SEO_URL/01-example/create_user.php`

want to change this into

`http://localhost/Interview/php/SEO_URL/01-example/CreateUser`

want to create a base url like this

`localhost/Interview/php/SEO_URL/01-example/`

How ?

Comment: I think we need more context here. Are you talking about URLs in links in a page? Please provide additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^interview/php/SEO_URI/01-example/create_user/?$ /Interview/php/SEO_URL/01-example/create_user.php [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect the requestd url :

- interview/php/SEO_URI/01-example/create_user

to

- /Interview/php/SEO_URL/01-example/create_user.php